Cloning uniswap v3 GetQuote
I am cloning my own version of uniswap for a new chain. I have deployed my version of the v3 contracts and I am using the interface from the uniswap github.
When entering a value in the swap form it calls https://interface.gateway.uniswap.org/v2/quote
but shows a warning in the console:
"GetQuote failed on Unified Routing API, falling back to client: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'routing')"
"GetQuote failed on client: Error: No address for Uniswap Multicall Contract on chain id:"
How can change it so that it uses my custom Multicall contract and gets a correct quote for my custom chain? I looked into deploying a version of the unified routing API, but the code in uniswap github doesnt seem to have a place to put the contract addresses.
